# Find best candidates in efficient way, Django

Tags: python, django

I'm beginner in django and python.
I have models :

```
 class Employee(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.full_name} ( {self.title} )"

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Candidate(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employee")
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="skill")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}: {self.employee} knows - {self.skill}"

class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True, related_name="Jobs")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

In views.py, i have 'finder' function :

```
def finder(job_id):
    job = Job.objects.get(id=job_id) # get the specific job
    relevant_candidates = [] # all the relevant candidates of this kob
    common = [] # number of common skills between the employee_skill and the 
    relevant_employees_by_title = Employee.objects.filter(title = job.title) # first filter the candidates by the job title 
    job_skills = []
    for skill in job.skills.all():
        print(skill.id)
        job_skills.append(skill.id)

    for employee in relevant_employees_by_title: 
        employee_skills =[]
        candidateCorrect = Candidate.objects.filter(employee__id = employee.id).values_list('skill', flat=True)
        for skill in candidateCorrect:
            employee_skills.append(skill)

        common_skills = list(set(job_skills) & set(employee_skills))
        
        if (len(common_skills)>0): #if there are common skills
            relevant_candidates.append(employee) 
            common.append(len(common_skills))

    candidates = zip(relevant_candidates,common)
    candidates = sorted(candidates,key = lambda t: t[1], reverse = True) # sort the candidates by the number of common skiils , descending order
    candidates = candidates[:50] # Select the best 50 candidates

    return candidates
```

This function get the job_id and need to find the best candidates for this job : first by matching between the job title to the employee title (for ex' : software developer), and then matching between candidate's skills to job's required skiils .

I think that my function is **inefficient**.
Someone has any idea how to write it in efficient way?

Comment: You can start by just filtering the candidates and skipping the employee lookup altogether `Candidate.objects.filter(employee__title=job.title)`

Comment: Additionally this question might be better suited to [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1):

First `Candidate` is not proper naming, renaming it to something makes more sense.

All you need is grouping; After you get `the skills`. do query `Candidate` `count` group by employee where skill in `the skills` order by count then limit.

here the example of group query

```py
Candidate.objects.values('employee').annotate(dcount=Count('employee')
#
```